# How Often Instagram Access Token Expire?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

There are many answers on this question but I did not get correct one.
I have integrated Instagram API to my application, and API call are on the basis on Access Token.

What If the **Access Token Expire**? Is there any solution to handle this problem?
Becaues this will stop working Insta feeds from my website and throw error.

Need help, suggestion, support, and solution!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instagram doesn't say anything solid in [it's documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.

In my experience the time varies broadly, even for the same app.
First token I obtained worked for about a year. The next one expired in two months. Third one lasted for two weeks (all for the same account and same application).